# MEF and WEB API 2.2

Tags: mef, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to inject dependencies into a Web Api Controller.

I created an own IHttpControllerActivator class and replaced the default one in lobalConfiguration.

```
 public class SimpleASPWebAPIContainer : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer container;

    public SimpleASPWebAPIContainer(CompositionContainer compositionContainer)
    {
        container = compositionContainer;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType != null)
        {
            var export = container.GetExports(controllerType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();

            IHttpController result = null;

            if (null != export)
            {
                result = export.Value as IHttpController;
            }
            else
            {
                //result = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
                //container.ComposeParts(result);
            }

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (container != null)
            container.Dispose();
    }
}

var apiSimpleContainer = new SimpleASPWebAPIContainer(container);

        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), apiSimpleContainer);
```

But when the client app is calling a controller method the IHttpControllerActivation Create method is not invoked.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

It was a very silly mistake.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        MefConfig.RegisterMef(config);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);


        AutoMapperConfig.InitAutoMapper();
    }
```

I should have to used the new HttoConfiguration instance to replace default IHttpControllerActivator instead of System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.